# Nginx and Apache on same domain

Tags: apache, nginx

I am running a vps with Ubuntu on it. On this server, I have a nginx server which hosts a wordpress website at port 80. I am trying to figure out how I can create a subdomain on my website to host an apache svn server from at an example url like: https://svn.example.com where my wordpress site is located at http://www.example.com

I have searched around quite a lot, and either I am missing the basic tutorials or there aren't any.

Could someone explain the basic process to me?

Comment: This is 3 future questions for SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

Run Apache on 443 port only (pure https), add virthost to it and add SVN to it, using **any** manual from Net